# Why if-else condition not working in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to display gender name based on condition in label using Thymeleaf, like if employee gender is 'F' then it should be display Female otherwise it should be display Male. Here down is issue which always displaying else condition.

```
        <center>
            <!-- IF -->
            <span th:if="${employee.gender == 'F'}">Female</span>
            <!-- ELSE -->
            <span th:unless="${employee.gender == 'F'}">Male</span>
        </center>
```

Comment: Hi Faeemazaz, i tried your answer.it still displaying else condtion only.and in my controller class gender type is enum.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try the following code, which is an inline evaluation form. Since you have two options (Male or Female) you can easily check for one option and then decide.

```
<center>
   <span th:text="${employee.gender == 'F'} ?  'Female' : 'Male'">Female</span>
</center>
```

Comment: Here also it displaying Male only!

Answer (score 2):

To compare with an enum constant try this:

```
<center>
    <th:block th:if="${user.gender == T(name.now).M}">
        <span>Female</span>
    </th:block>
    
    <th:block th:unless="${user.gender == T(name.now).M}">
        <span>Male</span>
    </th:block>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks Faeemazaz. i compared with including package name.now which is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

You check against **'F'** in both cases. Please change it to **'M'** for the unless expression.

```
<center>
   <!-- IF -->
    <span th:if="${employee.gender == 'F'}">Female</span>
   <!-- ELSE -->
    <span th:unless="${employee.gender == 'M'}">Male</span>
</center>
```

Comment: Hi Ahmet, thanks for response.yes i modifed as you said, still displaying else condtion value only

Comment: Then you should check your object gender value. Please debug it.

Comment: Yes,Ahmet i debugged, gender value is 'F' only.but it is always printing else condtion value.